# Is there anything more fundamental than axioms?

Tags: logic, axioms

If an axiom is the most fundamental form through which mathematics is defined then the objects defined should be completely characterized by the axioms. But that is not the case because some statements are undecidable.

My questions are:

If there is something more fundamental than axioms what is it?

If there isn't what is wrong with my deduction above?

Comment: formal logic maybe?

Comment: Our intuition about concepts.